# How to read specific part of large file in Python

Tags: python, parsing

Given a large file (hundreds of MB) how would I use Python to quickly read the content between a specific start and end index within the file?

Essentially, I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing:

```
open(filename).read()[start_index:end_index]
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can `seek` into the file the file and then read a certain amount from there. Seek allows you to get to a specific offset within a file, and then you can limit your read to only the number of bytes in that range.

```
with open(filename) as fin:
    fin.seek(start_index)
    data = fin.read(end_index - start_index)
```

That will only read that data that you're looking for.

Comment: note that this is only equivalent with OP's code for files with single-byte encoding (such as ASCII) or binary files because the OP's `start_index` and `end_index` are character position while `seek()` and `read()` works with byte position. When you have file with variable width encoding, you may have to decode the file to be able to index correctly.

Comment: That's a really good point. I was very much in ASCII mode :-)

Comment: One extra point: if you're trying to read multiple contiguous segments of a file, fin.read(n) automatically sets the read pointer to the next byte to be read.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution with variable width encoding. My CSV file contains a dictionary where each row is a new item.

```
def get_stuff(filename, count, start_index):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
             reader = csv.reader(infile)
             num = 0 
             for idx, row in enumerate(reader):
                 if idx >= start_index-1:
                     if num >= count:
                         return
                 else:
                     yield row 
                     num += 1
```

Comment: Hello @Will, there is an indentation problem in all your code starting at line 2

Comment: @BertrandGazanion sorry about that, should be fixed now