# How to extend a python script to compute large file?

Tags: python, file, counter

I got code to count  words in the  file.  It can work  for small files which is less than  500 MB. I have to keep the entire file in the memory before starting counting otherwise there will be errors in the count. This code reads file and store it to the RAM,process it. If I read line by line , there will be errors in the  count( `readline()`).

```
import collections
import codecs
from collections import Counter

with io.open('Prabhodhanam.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as infh:
    words =infh.read().split()
    with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f:
        for word, count in Counter(words).most_common(10000000):
            f.write(u'{} {}\n'.format(word, count).encode('utf8'))
```

When file is big it produces

```
Memory error
```

When  we use read line() `Counter()` tend to count words in the line  instead of whole file

How  to count the words without storing entire file to the memory ?

Comment: What problems are you facing while reading it line by line?

Comment: Any reason you can't count the words from a linux command line? ls -wc

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary  Word count is different, this cause errors

Comment: @Trent I have to do it i n python and words in the files are Unicode

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644859/how-to-read-specific-part-of-large-file-in-python

Please search well before asking.

Comment: @obayhan Please understand the problem

Comment: @karu I saw that, but what is causing that error? Please post a small sample of file that can reproduce the error count.

Comment: @karu Please read the link well.

Comment: @obayhan, here you have to count words

Comment: @obayhan OP's question is about counting the number of words in the file, reading a file in chunks will definitely result in incorrect answer.

Comment: @obayhan the problem is explained there  well , Please understand it

Comment: Isn't the question "Is there any way, to count the words without storing entire file to the memory "

???

So the solution is explained in the link. "Read the file with a help of pointer."  That solves yor problem. But if u are searching a person who will write your code instead of you yes that is not in the link....

Comment: @obayhan The problem is different, Please read the description

Comment: @karu: A small information.For large files u can try the code in Hadoop Platform.It will be better i think.There may be alternate ways.but jst informing u. :) Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check this code.
I dont know whether this helps or not.

```
def filePro(filename):
    f=open(filename,'r')
    wordcount=0
    for lines in f:
         f1=lines.split()
         wordcount=wordcount+len(f1)
    f.close()
    print 'word count:', str(wordcount)
filePro(raw_input("enter file name:"))
```

Comment: The problem is different here, it is not just counting

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to have the entire file in memory. You can count the words line by line (but of course you mustn't reset the counter after each line, so a list comprehension won't work here).

```
import collections
counter = collections.Counter()
with open('Prabhodhanam.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as infh:
    for line in infh:
        counter.update(line.strip().split())
with open('file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    for word, count in counter.most_common(10000000):
        f.write(u'{} {}\n'.format(word, count).encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: This assumes that words do not span multiple lines (as probably all other answers will).

Comment: A one-liner: `sum((Counter(line.split()) for line in f), Counter())`, but OP did mention that the line-by-line approach is not working for them, but the details were not sufficient. (You can drop the `str.rstrip` call as well)

Comment: @Tim, What happens, when  one word exists in  first line and  only in last line, what will be the count of that word

Comment: @karu why don't you test it?

Comment: @RedX, It increases memory usage and then stops

Comment: @karu stops in the sense that it completed its task or that it failed?

Comment: @RedX It means  Failed, It will not write the file or some time writes blank file

Comment: Are there any error messages? What is `len(counter)` just before writing the file? What is `counter["word"]` at this moment (substitute the word that exists only in the first and last line for `word`)? How much memory are you using? 10 million entries are a lot to write to a file, how much time are you giving it?  Can you see the output file grow as it's being written? Etc...we need more information for troubleshooting.

Comment: @Tim ,The memory usage  is increasing like  300Mb  to  2.75GB then it stops,  no error message. No output file generation . My input file contains around, 9000000 entries. The processor is in full utilization for 10 minutes

Comment: Are you using a 64bit version of Python on a 64bit OS? How many different words are there in your file?

Comment: Yes, I am using  Linux 64 bit version, Python is 64 bit.   In a rough count 1700504, Without including symbols