# Printing a section of a text file using python

Tags: python

I have a text document named `document1.txt`. The content of `document1` is given below.

```
VIA M2_M3_PWR 
        RESISTANCE 0.4 ;
        LAYER M2 ;
          RECT -1.35 -1.35 1.35 1.35 ;
        LAYER V2 ;                          # print
          RECT -1.35 -1.35 -0.45 1.35 ;     # these
          RECT 0.45 -1.35 1.35 -0.45 ;      # four
          RECT 0.45 0.45 1.35 1.35 ;        # lines
        LAYER M3 ;
          RECT -1.35 -1.35 1.35 1.35 ;
END M2_M3_PWR

VIA M3_MT DEFAULT
        RESISTANCE 1.5 ;
        LAYER M3 ;
          RECT -0.9 -0.45 0.9 0.45 ;
        LAYER V3 ;
          RECT -0.45 -0.45 0.45 0.45 ;
        LAYER MT ;
          RECT -0.45 -0.45 0.45 0.45 ;
END M3_MT

VIA IN1X
        TOPOFSTACKONLY 
        FOREIGN IN1X ;
        LAYER CUT01 ;
          RECT -0.45 -0.45 0.45 0.45 ;
        PROPERTY COUNT 1 ;
END IN1X
```

I am using Python and I would like to print a section of the file, say the region highlighted.

Comment: You tried regex yet?

Comment: Regex may be too much overhead. A custom grammar tokenizer will be better, but this requires a lot of heavy lifting. Maybe a bit too advanced for @biju.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read specific part of large file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644859/how-to-read-specific-part-of-large-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(LAYER\s*V2((?!LAYER).)*)
```

Try this.Grab the match.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/71

Comment: In Python this is: `re.search(r'(LAYER\s*V2((?!LAYER).)*)', open('document1.txt').read(), re.DOTALL).group().rstrip()`

Comment: I am new to python. I tried like this.

import re

ins = open( "document.txt", "r" )
t=ins.read()
k = re.search('(LAYER\s*V2((?!LAYER).)*)',t)
print k

But I am getting a message <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001D60690> instead of the required section. what correction should I make?

Comment: I had tried that. but when I give print k.groups, its giving the first line only, ie. the LAYER V2 only. not the following lines which appear before LAYER M3

Comment: @biju in yoru regex add `re.DOTALL`.

Comment: Suppose I need to parse an argument through command line instead of giving LAYER V2 so that I can print any part of this document through command line input. ie. I should be able to print from VIA M3_MT to END M3_MT or from LAYER CUT01 to PROPERTY through command line. What should be the modification?

Comment: @biju you can use `pattern=re.compile(r"")` to form your pattern.Then use `pattern.search(<your string>` or `pattern.match(<your string>)`

Comment: @biju it would be better if you can ask a new question .or else the correct answers will be changed.