# sed conditional merge NEXT line

Tags: python, regex, parsing, awk, sed

I have a log like below

```
10-26-2016 10:00:00 INFO bla bla bla
10-26-2016 10:00:00 ERROR This is the error
error line 2
error line 3
error line 4
10-26-2016 10:00:00 INFO bla bla bla2
```

I need a sed or a python command to get the error line below

```
==========================
his is the error
error line 2
error line 3
error line 4
==========================
```

This is a huge file and I cant open the file. Kindly assist. Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Marshall :  `sed -n '/^err/p' FILENAME`

Comment: I tried options like sed -n '/10-25-16 10.*ERROR/{N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;p;}' file | sed -n -e '/ERROR/p' -e '/^[^0-9]/p'  but going below some constant number of lines didnt work. because I may have some log under INFO level which does not start with a date value like DATA HOUR INFO bla bla bla(next line)  bla bla bla

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . AND don't try to explain your problem in comments, **update your Q** so people don't have to read a growing trail of comments to understand your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]/\n&/' file | sed -n '/ ERROR/,/^$/{s/^[0-9].* ERROR \(.*\)/\1/;/^$/d;p}'
```

Output:

```
This is the error
error line 2
error line 3
error line 4
```

---

**How it works:**

The first sed command (`sed 's/^[0-9]/\n&/' file`) inserts a blank line before every line which starts with a digit.

Output:

```
10-26-2016 10:00:00 INFO bla bla bla

10-26-2016 10:00:00 ERROR This is the error
error line 2
error line 3
error line 4

10-26-2016 10:00:00 INFO bla bla bla2
```

Second sed commnad prints only blocks which start with a line which contains `ERROR` and ends with a blank line. The part in curly brackets removes here `10-26-2016 10:00:00 ERROR` in this block and deletes the trailing blank line (`/^$/d`) in this block.

Remove `;/^$/d` if you want a blank line in output between different error blocks.

Comment: Cool. It worked. Can you please explain the command plz?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. How to get the out in one line ? like 
10-26-2016 10:00:00 ERROR This is the error error line 2 error line 3 error line 4

Comment: I suggest to start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand what you need, but here follows some code:

```
with open('long_file.log', 'r') as log_file:
    log = log_file.read().split('\n')
    for line in log:
        if 'error' in line:
            print (line)
```

Outputs:

```
10-26-2016 10:00:00 ERROR This is the error
error line 2
error line 3
error line 4
```

Comment: Sorry I cant open the file. it causes to much memory. I am reading n umber of file in a multi threaded way. so I cant open the entire file

Comment: Also word "error" may not occur in all the error lines. But it occurs only in first like "ERROR"

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm afraid I don't know how to help you then, sorry.

Comment: Actually, see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15644885/7067541

Comment: @Marshall: "loading a file" and "opening a file" are two different things. This current script doesn't load the whole file in memory but read it line by line.