# Read very long array from mat with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mat

I have a result file from Dymola (.mat v4) which stores all variables in a huge 1D array (More or less 2GB of data in one array...). I can't do anything about the file format as we are bound to use Dymola. When trying to read the file using scipy (with Python 2.7.13 64bit), I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\...\scipy\io\matlab\mio4.py:352: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered 
in long_scalars
remaining_bytes = hdr.dtype.itemsize * n
C:\...\scipy\io\matlab\mio4.py:172: RuntimeWarning: overflow 
encountered in long_scalars
num_bytes *= d
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 
...
self.mat = scipy.io.loadmat(fileName, chars_as_strings=False)
File "C:\...\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py", line 136, in loadmat
matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
File "C:\...\scipy\io\matlab\mio4.py", line 399, in get_variables
mdict[name] = self.read_var_array(hdr)
File "C:\...\scipy\io\matlab\mio4.py", line 374, in read_var_array
return self._matrix_reader.array_from_header(header, process)
File "C:\...\scipy\io\matlab\mio4.py", line 137, in array_from_header
arr = self.read_full_array(hdr)
File "C:\...\scipy\io\matlab\mio4.py", line 207, in read_full_array
return self.read_sub_array(hdr)
File "C:\...\scipy\io\matlab\mio4.py", line 178, in read_sub_array
"`variable_names` kwarg to `loadmat`" % hdr.name)
ValueError: Not enough bytes to read matrix 'data_2'; is this a badly-formed 
file? Consider listing matrices with `whosmat` and loading named matrices with `variable_names` kwarg to `loadmat`
```

The error/problem is pretty clear to me. My question: Are there any workarounds? Can I still read the file and get the data? Is it possible to split the array while reading it?

Comment: Possible duplicate... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644859/how-to-read-specific-part-of-large-file-in-python

Comment: I disagree. This is certainly **not a duplicate** of the question linked above.

Comment: @littleHue Can you please be specific in how you interpret the error? Although the message may be clear to you it may not be clear to everyone who may know a solution, or your interpretation could be wrong. -- As far I understand the error message the file is damaged.

Comment: Hi, the difference to the linked question is the file format. I'm not sure if I can read a .mat-File with fseek/read.
@kazemakase: The array has more entries than long_int allows. That's because of the stupid format Dymola uses to save its results. The crucial error message is: overflow encountered 
in long_scalars
remaining_bytes = hdr.dtype.itemsize * n

Comment: @littleHue please excuse my silly question - i'm not familiar with Dymola. Are you saying that Dymola saves results in Matlab's .mat file format but does not adhere to the specification? Or is the file fine and there is a bug in scipy's `loadmat` routine?

Comment: @kazemakase: No silly question at all. Yes: Dymola is just a tool using Matlabs file format. Not sure about the specification, but since matlab can't read the files: Probably yes. Dymola can read the file, so it is not corrupt, but an array with probably > 4*10^9 entries is at least questionable. I would give everything for another tool but well... Hence the question if I can do anything.

Comment: @littleHue This does not sound good :( If not even Matlab can load the file Dymola must be doing something weird indeed. I guess you have two options: 1. Hack the scipy routines to circumvent the error (if possible), 2. Write your own loader according to the specification ([PDF](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf)), 0. Get Dymola to export in a different format - but that's probably not an option.

Comment: I might end up with option 2 but hoped, I could avoid it. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you turn on conversion to SDF file format which is based on HDF5. This format can better handle large files. See Simulation/Setup.

Alternatively you can reduce the number of variables stored in the file using Variable Selections in Dymola.

Comment: Can I read a SDF file with scipy or hdf5py? Otherwise, I'll end up with the same problems as before as I need to write my own loader. Reducing the number of variables can be done but isn't a nice solution as I hate to throw away valuable data.

Comment: Yes. SDF is just a mapping onto native HDF5. There are some Python scripts in Dymola too to help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try. Much more convenient than rewriting the mat-Reader :-)