# How to create a dependency tree for python functions

Tags: python, dependencies

I'm writing some code using python/numpy that I will be using for data analysis of some experimental data sets. Certain steps of these analysis routines can take a while. It is not practical to rerun every step of the analysis every time (I.E when debugging) so it makes sense to save the output from these steps to a file and just reuse them if they're already available.

The data I ultimately want to obtain can be derived from various steps along this analysis process. I.E, A can be used to calculate B and C. D can be calculated from B. E can then be calculated using C and D. etc etc.

The catch here is that it's not uncommon to make it through a few (or many) datasets only to find that there's some tiny little gotcha in the code somewhere that requires some part of the tree to be recalculated. I.E - I discover a bug in B, so now anything that depends on B also needs to be recalculated because it was derived from incorrect data.

The end goal here is to basically protect myself from having sets of data that I forget to reprocess when bugs are found. In other words, I want to be confident that all of my data is calculated using the newest code.

Is there a way to implement this in Python? I have no specific form this solution needs to take so long as it's extensible as I add new steps. I also am okay with the "recalculation step" only being performed when the dependent quantity is recalculated (Rather than at the time one of the parents are changed).

My first thought of how this might be done is to embed information in a header of each saved file (A, B, C, etc) indicating what version of each module it was created with. Then, when loading the saved data the code can check if the version in the file matches the current version of the parent module. (Some sort of `parent.getData()` which checks if the data has been calculated for that dataset and if it's up to date)

The thing is, at least at first glance, I could see that this could have problems when the change happens several steps up in the dependency chain because the derived file may still be up to date with its module even though *its* parents are out of date. I suppose I could add some sort of `parent.checkIfUpToDate()` that checks its own files and then asks each of *its* parents if they're up to date (which then ask their parents, etc), and updates it if not. The version number can just be a static string stored in each module.

My concern with that approach is that it might mean reading potentially large files from disk just to get a version number. If I went with the "file header" approach, does Python actually load the whole file in to memory when I do an `open(myFile)`, or can I do that, just read the header lines, and close the file without loading the whole thing in to memory?

Last - is there a good way to embed this type of information beyond just having the first line of the file be some variation of `# MyFile made with MyModule V x.y.z` and writing some piece of code to parse that line?

I'm kind of curious if this approach makes sense, or if I'm reinventing the wheel and there's already something out there to do this.

edit: And something else that occurred to me after I submitted this - does Python have any mechanism to define templates that modules must follow? Just as a means to make sure I keep the format for the data reading steps consistent from module to module.

Comment: are you looking for something like this , but for python ? https://github.com/pahen/madge (I am too)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer all of your questions but you can read in only a small part of data from a large file as you can see here:

[How to read specific part of large file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644859/how-to-read-specific-part-of-large-file-in-python)

I do not see why you would need a `parent.checkIfUpToDate()` function. You could as well just store the version number of the parent functions in the file itself as well. 
To me your approach sounds reasonable, however I have never done anything similar. Alternatively you could create an additional file that holds the specified information but I think storing the information in the actual file should prevent Version errors between your "data file" and the "function version file".