# how to parse a multiline into tuple

Tags: python

I have file in format:

```
name : base : add : data1 : data2 : {desc}
name : base : add : data1 : data2 : {desc}
name : base : add : data1:  data2 : {desc
desc-continue}
name : base : add : data1:  data2 : {desc
desc-contiue
desc-continue}
...
name : base : add : data1 : data2 : {desc}
```

As you can see desc starts and end with {}, but can be across multiple line.

as such, I can't use reg = Register._match(line.split(r/ : /)

Any help on how to parse this file effectively in python.

Comment: If you need to read that file into single line, just split by `}`, then append later

Answer (score 0):

Split by `}` then append later.

```py
a = """name : base : add : data1 : data2 : {desc}
name : base : add : data1 : data2 : {desc}
name : base : add : data1:  data2 : {desc
desc-continue}
name : base : add : data1:  data2 : {desc
desc-contiue
desc-continue}"""
splited = [i+"}" for i in a.split("}") if i]
```

Result:

```py
>>>splited
['name : base : add : data1 : data2 : {desc}', '\nname : base : add : data1 : data2 : {desc}', '\nname : base : add : data1:  data2 : {desc\ndesc-continue}', '\nname : base : add : data1:  data2 : {desc\ndesc-contiue\ndesc-continue}']
```

Comment: Thanks. My file is of a decent size, any suggestions for not reading a whole file.

Comment: @Romeo, that is a nother question, bro. Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644859/how-to-read-specific-part-of-large-file-in-python