# Looking for RAM efficient way to compare many distributions in parallel in Python

Tags: python, memory, ram

I have to compare each distribution of measurement n, with all other measurements. I have about 500 measurements and 5000 distributions per measurement, so that's a lot of comparisons. I have the data in one csv file:

|  | distribution 1 | distribution 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **measurement 1** | [10,23,14,16,28,19,28] | [4,1,3,2,5,8,4,2,4,6] |
| **measurement 2** | [11,23,24,10,27,19,27] | [9,2,5,2,5,7,3,2,4,1] |

as you can imagine the file is huge and as I have to do many comparisons I run it in parallel and the RAM consumption is insane. If I split the file and only open sample by sample, it's a bit better, but still not good and also it's not very efficient.

My idea was to create some kind of database and query only the cells needed, but have never done it, so I don't know if that will be RAM heavy and fairly efficient.

Comment: Are you looking for identical distrbutions or similar? If similar, how do you define similar? Are your distributions really of differing lengths... 7 or 8 samples?

Comment: A possible approach might be to learn how to code in compiled languages like [Ocaml](https://ocaml.org/), C or C++, some Common Lisps like [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) etc.... Also read about databases like [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) or [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) and [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: How are you reading the file? Do you read the entire file at once? Could you maybe quarter it, solve the quarters, and then quarter it differently until you get all the data?
Btw. It doesn't have to be quarters, you could specify the max MB / objects/rows used.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644859/how-to-read-specific-part-of-large-file-in-python

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes, the distributions are different lengths anywhere from 50-200... I'm calculating a p-value, so I need the actual numbers from the distributions.

Answer (score 1):

This probably has something to do with destroying objects. The way to limit RAM usage would be to limit the number of threads. Then you don't start every comparison at the beginning and then solve them by four (assuming you have four threads per process) to end an hour later to let the garbage collector start destroying objects of the solved cases.

I am just spitballing here. A bit of code would be helpful. Maybe you are already doing that?